# FCM BigQuery - No MESSAGE_DELIVERED records returned

Tags: android, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have called `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true)` in my Android project, but I cannot see `MESSAGE_DELIVERED` in the BigQuery result. Details as below.

I had built up my Android project with FCM integrated for several months. And also enabled export FCM data to BigQuery.

In BigQuery editor, I have `SELECT event_timestamp, event FROM` android_0901xxx.firebase_messaging.data `WHERE app_name = 'com.company.mydemo' and sdk_platform  = 'ANDROID'  ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC`, the query result is as below:

[image]

As you see, all of the events are `MESSAGE_ACCEPTED`, but I have confirmed tons times, I can receive the notification on my Android devices. And I also tapped the notifications.

So my question is how come I cannot get other events like `MESSAGE_DELIVERED` in my BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#what-data-exported) the message has been delivered to the app's FCM SDK on the device. By default, MESSAGE_DELIVERED is not propagrated. To enable, follow the instructions provided in [`setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(boolean)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#public-void-setdeliverymetricsexporttobigquery-boolean-enable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have called FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true) in my Android project, still cannot get the MESSAGE_DELIVERED events in the BigQuery result. Any other idea?

Comment: Please try adding the following property to the application object in your app manifest: <application>
  <meta-data android:name="delivery_metrics_exported_to_big_query_enabled"
      android:value="true" />
</application>

Comment: If you have already added this, I recommend you to file a support case by following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support)